# scala play framework 2.5 and per request metrics design

Tags: scala, playframework, metrics, playframework-2.5

I'm in the process of designing a system that will collect per request metrics. Most of the metric libraries I've looked at collect metrics for the overall server and not per request. What I am interested in is specifically per request metrics (time spent for the whole request, number of database calls, time spent per database call, time spent calling an external http endpoint, time spent calculating something). I noticed that there is no http or request context that I can append metrics to as I call my REST API. How could I collect all these metrics and send them somewhere (syslog, console, webpage). It's important that the metrics from one request don't mix with the metrics from another request. How could I achieve this? Using Play Filters, or Play Actions ? Also, I'd appreciate any code example illustrating your point or idea.

Thanking you in advance

Comment: NewRelic? Or maybe http://kamon.io/

Comment: Try having a look at codahale metrics!

Comment: I'm looked at codahale. I didn't find anything that allowed me to collect metrics per request. It only collected metrics for the overall server which is what I don't want. Unless I missed something, could you elaborate more on how to do it?

Comment: https://github.com/kenshoo/metrics-play

Comment: Kamon Tracing Module is what I'm looking for but it's not compatible with play 2.5

Comment: github.com/kenshoo/metrics-play doesn't do per request metrics unless I'm missing something.